# Pass database values to checkbox using JavaFX 8

Tags: database, sqlite, checkbox, javafx-8

I've looked everywhere to find how to pass SQLite database values to a checkbox.  This is for computer software used on a desktop or laptop.  I doubt my programming would help anyone help me.  Does anyone have ANY ideas at all?

Here is some code:

```
try {
        if (this.colSeason.equals("Summer")){
            cbSummer.isSelected();
        }else {
            cbFall.isSelected();
        }
        if (this.colHeirHyb.equals("Heirloom")) {
            cbHeir.isSelected();
        }else
            cbHyb.isSelected();
        if (colOrg.equals("Organic")){
            cbOrg.isSelected();
        }else {
            cbNonOrg.isSelected();
        }
        if (colSowing.equals("Sow in Flats")){
            cbFlats.isSelected();
        }else cbDirect.isSelected();
        if (colSaved.equals("Bought")){
            cbBought.isSelected();
        }else {
            cbSaved.isSelected();
        }
```

Comment: Share some code snippets what you are trying to do.

Comment: Get the value from the database, convert it to boolean, if necessary and pass the value to [the `setSelected` method of the `CheckBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/CheckBox.html#setSelected-boolean-). What part are you having problems with???

Comment: Thanks, Fabian!  That worked perfectly!